# django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'department_name' into field

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

How to use serializers.SlugRelatedField Correctly?
My code is look like this but it got an error...
There is the full error:
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'department_name' into field. Choices are: badge, created_at, department, department_id, gender, id, name, position, position_id, updated_at

Model Code:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('Male', 'Male'),
        ('Female', 'Female'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    badge = models.CharField(max_length=6, unique=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=GENDER_CHOICES)
    department = models.ForeignKey(
        Department, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    position = models.ForeignKey(
        Position, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name} - {self.badge}'
```

Serializer Code

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Employee


class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    department = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        slug_field='department_name', queryset=Employee.objects.all())
    # position = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
    #     slug_field='position_name', queryset=Employee.objects.all()

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Serializer code, do this

```
slug_field='department', queryset=Employee.objects.all())
```

It is because you dont't have any such field named 'department_name' in your 'Employee' Model class.

Comment: Got this error AttributeError: 'Department' object has no attribute 'department'
There is my Department model
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.


class Department(models.Model):
    department_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    department_head = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.department_name} - {self.department_head}'

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure SlugFiled is the best choice?

to get department name, you can use this:

```
department = serializers.CharField(source="department.department_name")
```

but your department FK is null-able and this would be better one:

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    department = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = '__all__'

    @staticmethod
    def get_department(obj):
        return obj.department.department_name if obj.department else None
```

Comment: i got this error for now, but i think its better to use serializer.CharField() like you said, 
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Employee` instance.
Original exception text was: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'department_name'.

Comment: like i said, you are allowing null value as ForeignKey, you need to check if department is null.   so you should use SerializerMethodField to avoid any exception

Comment: im using SerializerMethodField now, but i cant get Department field on my API, sorry for my bad english, there is a image https://imgur.com/a/9K5yZLr